# Download files from private S3 folder using cloudfront

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

This is the bucket policy I have:

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity dydcrrxfc"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name
            ]
        }
```

I want to download files in S3 folder through coufront URL.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: what's the error you are getting when trying to download files through CloudFront URL.

Comment: When I am hitting URL it is not showing any error and neither response. Screen just wen't blank after hitting URL

Comment: That sounds very strange. You might want to wait a while for the CloudFront distribution to setup completely. Then, try accessing a file that does _not_ exist, to see if it generates an error.